# Getting a Scala interpreter to work

Tags: macos, shell, scala, terminal, installation

I'm very new to Scala. I have downloaded it, got it working in Eclipse where I'll be developing it; but I can't make it work in Terminal.

All sites and books say to just type `scala` - this doesn't work.

The [website](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/166) infuriatingly says:

> We assume that both the Scala software and the user environment are
>   set up correctly.

**How do I do that bit?**

I'm very new to this, and using Jargon or assuming too much knowledge of frameworks around Scala will ruin a good response; please keep it simple.

- Mac OS X (10.6.7)
- Scala: 2.9.0.1

Thank you

Comment: For OS X, I highly recommend Homebrew (http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/).  Then you can easily `brew install scala` and scala will be installed and ready to go.  Not to mention all the other very cool things you can easily install with Homebrew.  MacPorts or Fink may have something similar, but I prefer Homebrew.

Comment: @dave - You really should upgrade that from a comment to full answer status.

Comment: @kevin - And now it's an answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 85, accepted):

For OS X, I highly recommend [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).

The [installation of Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew) is incredibly easy.  Once installed, you just need to run `brew install scala` and scala will be installed and ready to go.  Homebrew also has tons of other goodies just a `brew install` away.

If you don't already have Java installed, you can install that with `brew cask install java`.

[MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) or [Fink](https://www.finkproject.org/) may have something similar, but I prefer Homebrew.

Comment: Make sure we have Java installed or else brew will complain

Answer (score 15):

Not a big fan of cluttering up my `PATH` variable. I just symlink all my programs to /usr/local/bin, which is in the classpath. For example, if you downloaded scala and uncompress it in /opt/scala-2.9.0-1, run the following in the terminal.

```
ln -s /opt/scala-2.9.0-1/bin/scala /usr/local/bin
```

Now just type `scala` in the terminal and you're all set.
This way you don't have to set your `PATH` or change it when you have a new version of scala you want to try out. If you download a new version, you can uncompress it in any location and symlink the new version. Say you download version 2.9.1 and uncompress it in /opt/scala-2.9.1. You can type the following in the terminal

```
ln -s /opt/scala-2.9.1/bin/scala /usr/local/bin/scala2.9.1
```

Now, to use scala 2.9.1 you just run `scala2.9.1` at the terminal.
When you are ready to switch to 2.9.1 fulltime, just update the symlink.

You could also add scaladoc, scalac, scalap and others in the same way

```
ln -s /opt/scala-2.9.0-1/bin/scalac /usr/local/bin
ln -s /opt/scala-2.9.0-1/bin/scalap /usr/local/bin
ln -s /opt/scala-2.9.0-1/bin/scaladoc /usr/local/bin
ln -s /opt/scala-2.9.0-1/bin/fsc /usr/local/bin
ln -s /opt/scala-2.9.0-1/bin/sbaz /usr/local/bin
ln -s /opt/scala-2.9.0-1/bin/sbaz-setup /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to add `scala\bin` to your `PATH` environment variable.

On Mac OS X the path to Scala bin is usually: `/Users/<your username>/scala/bin` and on Windows usually: `C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin`.

On Mac OS X use the Terminal and write (using your username):

```
echo 'export PATH=/Users/<your username>/scala/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

then close the Terminal and start it again.

Comment: PATH environment variable? (sorry!)

Comment: echo 'export PATH=/Users/Alex/Downloads/scala-2.9.0.1 2/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.profile     ... didn't do anything. Should it?

Comment: no just, close your termina, start it again and type `scala` and press enter.

Comment: You can always try to start Scala with `/Users/Alex/Downloads/scala-2.9.0.1 2/bin/scala` that should work.

Comment: @Alex coady - Careful about that space between 2.9.0.1 and 2.  You need to make sure it's a command--so it probably should be `2.9.0.1\ 2/`

Comment: @Alex: You can try to write it to `~/.bash_profile` instead of `~/.profile` that didn't work for me. But `~/.bash_profile` work for me. I have updated the command in my answer.

Comment: do close the terminal and open a new session to see your changes reflected

Answer (score 4):

Scala recommends using Homebrew to install the Typesafe stack for Scala 2.9.2.

```
brew install scala sbt maven giter8
```

Homebrew will install soft links in `/usr/local/bin` for `sbt`, `scala`, `scalac`, `scaladoc`, `scalap`, `fsc` and `g8`. Follow the soft links to its final referent in order to determine where $SCALA_HOME needs to be. $SCALA_HOME should contain `bin/scala` and `lib/scala-compiler.jar`.

Typesafe recommends using `sbt console` instead of `scala` to get the interpreter going, because `sbt` will also manage library dependencies to libraries such as Akka. That said, if you want to use `scala`, `scalac`, `fsc`, `scalac` and `scaladoc` directly, you may need to run a `chmod +x` on the referents of the soft links.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to add more directories to your path, try these steps:

1. Download Scala from the [downloads pages](http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads).
2. Unzip and then copy the folder to \Library\Scala.
3. Find the complete path to the bin directory, which should be \Library\Scala\scala-2.9.2\bin.
4. Find the "scala" file, right click, and Make Alias.
5. Move the alias file anywhere it's convenient, such as your desktop.
6. Double click the alias to start Scala in the Terminal.

Comment: Would be better be able to type "Scala" in terminal, but this works. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My way of making Scala run every time you type "scala" in Terminal was to add the path not to the .bashrc file but to the /etc/paths one.

1. Download the latest Scala binary from [www.scala-lang.org/download](http://www.scala-lang.org/download)
2. Unzip the binary file
3. Move the unzipped folder (named scala-2.11.2) to the /usr/bin/ or some other directory of your preference.
4. Then open the /etc/paths file with nano:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/paths
   ```
5. and add this line to the end:

   ```
   /usr/bin/scala-2.11.2/bin
   ```
6. Press Ctrl+X to exit nano and answer "Yes" when prompted to overwrite the file
7. Then **restart** Terminal and once you type:

   ```
   scala
   ```

   you will get the scala command line that looks like this:

   ```
   Welcome to Scala version 2.11.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_05).
   Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
   Type :help for more information.

   scala>
   ```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded scala with macports try typing scala-2.9 (or whatever is the filename of the contents of folder /opt/local/bin/scala/)

(At least this works for OSX mountain lion)

Comment: This is what I had to do. I then did `sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/scala-2.9 /opt/local/bin/scala` for convenience. Mac Ports is normally way less infuriating than Homebrew, but not this time.

Answer (score 0):

Just install Scala with : `$ brew install scala` so you can use `$scala` in terminal to evaluate scala instructions , for now the official Scala website recommend installing scala with sbt : `$ brew install sbt` which won't let you `scala` keyword in terminal