# Install scala on Mac OSX Lion

Tags: scala

http://cingusoft.posterous.com/install-scala-on-mac-os-x

I changed .profile and save. after I type

> source .profile

at first it works, but after I close terminal and re-opened, It doesn't work.

How do I this problem?

[Getting a Scala interpreter to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230511/getting-a-scala-interpreter-to-work)

I solved on my own.

Comment: On OS X i prefer brew to install SW. Install brew: "https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation" then you can install scala or other tools with "brew install scala". And "brew install sbt"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add this line to your shell autoload file: .bashrc for bash or .zshrc for zsh.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand. please any code for this? I'm newbie in unix;

Comment: If you type `echo $SHELL` you'll find what shell you're using.
If it's bash you'll have to add `export PATH="/Users/your_user/scala/bin:$PATH"` to your .bashrc file.

Answer (score 0):

**Latest MacOS Catalina Scala deployment with Apache Spark and Kafka:**

1. Install Brew

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

2. Install Java JDK8

```
brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8
```

3. Install SBT

```
brew install set
```

4. Install Scala (latest 2.13.3)

```
brew install scala
```

5. Install Spark (latest 3.0.0)

```
brew install apache-spark
```

6. Install Kafka (latest 2.5.0)

```
brew install kafka
```

7. Etc. for Cassandra

```
brew install cassandra ...
```

Latest Ubuntu 20.04 "One-Click" deployment:

```
curl -Lo cs https://git.io/coursier-cli-linux && chmod +x cs && ./cs setup
```